# Pass parameters - Shopify Script Tag API

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I'm posting a solution to this question since I didn't find a precise answer to this. It might be useful to someone.
Here's what needs to be done.

Pass your data in the form of query string params.Example, `https://web.page.com/yourFile.js?param1=something&paramm2=something`. 
Also, note that the `shop=` param is automatically appended to the final version of your script that is injected on the Shopify's liquid template.

Final version of the script in the template looks something like this.
`<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://web.page.com/yourFile.js?param1=something&paramm2=something&shop=yourshop.myshopify.com"></script>`

Once this is done, get the final **URL** (containing params) in `yourFile.js` in the following way.
`var url = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].src`

Now, using the method below, you can get the values of your parameters.

```
function getParameterByName(paramName, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the point is of passing parameters to a script tag, but whatever floats your boat. You also have App Proxy calls at your disposal in your toolbox, allowing your script tag code to make callbacks specific to the shop, to load up on needed parameters. Much power using that pattern. Clean and flexible.

Comment: floats your boat.. :D

Comment: This makes sense for passing config data to another script via Shopify's Admin ScriptTag API. I see you @Abhilash.